# How can I tell if my two-pronged outlets have ground wires behind them?

Tags: receptacle, grounding

I have two-pronged outlets in my apartment. They look like this:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to check whether they have a ground or not? Some guides talk about use a circuit tester and touching the screw, but I don't even see a screw? It seems like they've been painted over. Maybe I need to chip away at the paint?

On top of that, how would I even remove these?

Comment: Use a SHARP utility knife to carefully cut the paint around the outlet, With the screw out it should pop off with a bit of persuasion. Whether is has ground internally or not... the screw test thing might work, but you will not know for sure till you open it.

Comment: Having said that.. it looks VERY OLD. The insulation on the wires may be brittle so a delicate touch opening it is required.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to know?

Comment: @Trevor at that age it's possible that a ground is available via metallic conduit or metallic cable.    In that era the center screw could be grounded as it would screw into the metal yoke which is attached to the metal box.  It has many more flaws than today's standards but it's not as impossible as your comments imply.

Comment: @bib I want to know how easily my outlets can be made grounded.

Comment: Ya I know @Tyson I just meant if the screw test fails, it does not necessarily mean there is no ground available behind.

Answer (score 5):

What's the point of making them grounded? Either a) safety or b) to plug in 3-prong plugs.  There are several ways to do that.

You see the hole on your second photo? That's where the single screw *goes*.   On your first photo, the screw is covered with many layers of paint.

I would not stick a spike in there and gore up the threads.  Just get the proper screw.  *They come free* with outlet covers, which cost 30 cents.  Sand the paint off the head if you mean to put a voltage probe on it.

At this point, the layers of paint will have schellacked the outlet covers to the wall, and you'll need some careful knife work to separate them. Err on the side of damaging the outlet cover. They make oversize outlet covers for a neater appearance in this situation (not 30 cents). And next time you paint, *take the covers off first*.

### Safety

If you can live with 2-prong outlets, you can render those safe by feeding them from a GFCI breaker or receptacle upstream.  Since GFCI breakers cost more than receptacles, especially for some archaic panels, I have been known to put a receptacle inches away from the panel and feed the whole circuit from that.  Plug a nightlight into every outlet in the house to make sure you don't have any crossed neutrals that would prevent the GFCI from working.  Put "GFCI protected" labels on all protected receptacles.

### 3-prong outlets

If you have provided GFCI protection, it is legal to fit a 3-prong receptacle if you also add a sticker saying "No Equipment Ground".   If that sounds like it doesn't protect equipment, exactly - some equipment cares about that for non-safety reasons, e.g. being sensitive to "static electricity" (ESD).

If you want *real* grounded outlets, and you don't have good ground in the junction box, you can **retrofit ground**.  This is easier than pulling all new grounded cable, since it's a single bare wire, and since every circuit served out of the same panel can share ground wires.  The only requirement is that the ground path be thick enough its entire length; so plan for this.  Runs to your heavy appliances (range, dryer, water heater) can be a backbone for the other grounds to connect to.

Comment: Is GFCI really as safe as having a proper ground? I've read some stuff that seemed to indicate it wasn't quite the same.

Comment: @alecb -- from the perspective of "not getting shocked", yes -- a GFCI will disconnect an appliance that tries to bite you.  There are other reasons to have an EGC, but those aren't nearly as relevant to safety as the shock protection aspects

Comment: @alecb A GFCI is safer than a proper ground. Current flows in loops, and it is measuring whether all the current which went out, came back.   If any current is unaccounted for, it is taking an "alternate path" home, i.e. through you.   Grounds do not provide this protection, much the opposite, they help provide an alternate path.

Comment: I'm concerned about my own safety but also the safety of my electrical equipment (eg, not causing damage to a PC). For both/either of those considerations, is there a reason to prefer a proper ground to a GFCI?

Comment: A proper ground is better than GFCI if you care about equipment damage more than human life risk.  Appalling as that sounds, there are many cases where it may be appropriate,if given your equipment and circumstances, equipment damage is a high risk, and human safety a rather low risk.   *We've been doing things that way for 60 years, it must be the best, right?*

Comment: @Harper, I think you're a little harsh on proper ground.  It's there to provide an alternate path to ground, but for the purpose of _triggering_ GFCI or fuse protection without the need to introduce a human into the circuit.  It can be the difference between the GFCI tripping when you plug in faulty equipment and it tripping while you're using faulty equipment.

Comment: @sh1 sure. But GFCI directly does what you want.  Ground was the best we could come up with back when GFCI was impractical. And it is better onthe large than nothing. But a well distributed earthing system actially makes hot more dangerous because it gives you more ways to complete the circuit. Every strategy is a gamble; NFPA ran the numbers and said grounding is better than an isolated system.  But GFCI may change the math.

Comment: Well, the ground conductor is meant to encapsulate live components (via chassis) so that the first thing they touch causes a fault (historically overcurrent, but now residual current) before a human can get anywhere near them.  Without ground you need a human to pick the device up and touch something with a ground connection, or stand in a puddle, or touch a faucet, etc.  Grounding still, generally, supports the early and safe discovery of faults and should really be used in conjunction with GFCI.  That on top of all the noise and parasitic regions it should be present.

Comment: @sh1 that *was* the idea, back when anything had a metal chassis. I prefer grounds too.  My goal here is to deflate 60 years of industry propaganda that ground is **the only** path to safety.

Comment: @Harper Are a ground and GFCI mutually exclusive? If I care about my equipment can I install a ground, and then install a GFCI to further protect myself. Does GFCI provide *any* benefit to equipment protection compared to having neither GFCI or a ground?

Comment: Absolutely do both!  We think of GFCI's as things which protect humans first. But the fact is, without a GFCI, a current fault could go on for a long time, which can only be bad for equipment.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost no chance you'll find a ground in an outlet like that. A very sharp point driven into the middle screw will make enough contact to allow you to use a multimeter, if you need to try...

Although you clarified that you aren't renting (my original answer had a note about chargeable damages), I'll note that you'll inevitably do damage to the finish paint if you pull off the cover plate. If you actually pull the outlet out of the wall, you'd run the risk of damaging the cranky old wiring. (Results of that can range from benign to really bad.)

Comment: It's a coop, I'm not renting. But okay, good to know.

Comment: Even if you do make it to the screw, on something that old there is no guarantee the screw is connected to any ground behind it.  The screw may just go into the "plastic" body of the socket.

Comment: If it's NM, it's certainly ungrounded.  A conduit or BX job would likely have a ground at the center screw though...

Comment: @Trevor -- the screw basically *always* goes into the receptacle's metal yoke (or at least that's my understanding of how receptacles were/are constructed)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes that's the way it's supposed to be, but like I said in the other thread... if the test passes.. great.. if it fails you still need to look behind and see if there is grounding that is not connected to the outlet / screw.